# Intent? Class name not matching path

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I am simply trying to start my program but appear to have difficultly getting past this error.  I did some researching and it seems to be linked with intent.  I have double-checked my manifest file (which will be posted below) and the package names appear to be correct.

One thing that did catch my eye was the second line of the exception log.  It is looking for

`class "com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000" on path:`

at `/data/app/com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000-1.apk`

Is that '-1' supposed to be there?

```
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000/com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000.BluetoothTransferActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000.BluetoothTransferActivity" on path: /data/app/com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000-1.apk
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000.BluetoothTransferActivity" on path: /data/app/com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000-1.apk
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2220)
04-10 16:04:49.182: E/AndroidRuntime(30008):    ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: this `BluetoothTransferActivity` is nowhere in your apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the name of the `activity` into the `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name="com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000"
```

That´s the cause of the `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000.BluetoothTransferActivity" on path: /data/app/com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000-1.apk
```

Add the name of your activity "`BluetoothTransferActivity`" into the `Manifest.xml`:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.project.BluetoothTransfer_v1000.BluetoothTransferActivity"
```